# Why Java basic variable assignment is not atomic

Tags: java

all. I run following code to test whether Java basic variable assignment is atomic or not.

```
public class Test  {
static int x = 1 << 16 - 1, y = -1 << 16, i = x;
static volatile boolean flag = false;
public static void main(String... args) {
    ExecutorService executors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    executors.execute(() -> {
        while (true) {
            if (flag) {
                return;
            }
            i = x;
        }
    });
    executors.execute(() -> {
        while (true) {
            if (flag) {
                return;
            }
            i = y;
        }
    });
    executors.execute(() -> {
        while (true) {
            if (i != x && i != y && (flag = true)) {
                System.out.println(i + "," + x + "," + y);
                throw new RuntimeException("Not Equal!!");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It will throw a new exception(Follow text ), but i can not catch the actual i when condition (i != x && i != y) is true, because other thread will modify the variable i at same time.

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-3" java.lang.RuntimeException: Not Equal!!
at common.Test.lambda$main$2(Test.java:31)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

32768,32768,-65536

Can someone give some useful advices to help me to find out the actual i which cause (if (i != x && i != y && (flag = true)) is true?

Comment: `flag = true`? or did you mean: `flag == true` which means that you can simply do: `...&& flag`

Comment: I just set flag true to let other thread exit

Comment: I don't think "atomic" is the word you're looking for.  With the exception of `long` and `double`, all assignments are atomic.  But without synchronization, the assigned value may not be visible to other threads.

Comment: The point is, it may not be the same value. Try `int myI = i; if (myI ...)`

Comment: I find out condition (i != x && i != y) is wrong, because when code judge (i ! =x) , i may be y , and judge (i ! =y) , y may be x

Comment: Thanks all. I just want to prove java basic variable(int, short) assignment is atomic. Can someone give some advices?

Comment: Finally, i change the strategy。I use local variable to store the variable i, then to see the condition (i != x && i != y && (flag = true)) is true or not. It works. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're seeing is not because int assignment is not atomic: it is!

Since you're modifying `i` from multiple threads all reads and writes to it should be synchronized otherwise threads might get stale values and that's what happens in your case, example:

1. assignment `i = y`
2. this condition is evaluated: `if (i != x && i != y && (flag = true))`
3. `i != x` is evaluated and returns `true`
4. assignment `i = x`
5. `i != y` is evaluated and returns `true`
6. we're inside the `if`

Comment: yes, I find out condition (i != x && i != y) is wrong, because when code judge (i ! =x) , i may be y , and judge (i ! =y) , i may be x .

Comment: I'm not sure what's "judge" but I think you got it.

Comment: Finally, i change the strategy。I use local variable to store the variable i, then to see the condition (i != x && i != y && (flag = true)) is true or not. It works. Thanks all.